# multiple condition for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

May I ask how do I put in multiple condition in a javascript ?

Currently the button is to be enable when it meets the 1st condition when checkbox is checked.

I'm trying to add two more condition if the 2nd conditon when any checkbox is checked also and the 3rd condition is when the user selected the dropdown list.

I try to test with `if (checkbox.checked === true) && ()` but got an console error.

1st condition:

```
<p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions             
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onchange="isChecked(this,'sub1')"/></p>
```

2nd condition:

```
 <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' value='{$CD['CDID']}' title='{$CD['CDPrice']}' /></span>
```

3rd condition:

```
<section id="placeOrder">
            <h2>Place order</h2>
            Your details
            Customer Type: <select id="show" name="customerType" onchange="change(this)">
                <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
                <option value="ret">Customer</option>
                <option value="trd">Trade</option>
            </select>
```

JS:

```
function isChecked(checkbox, sub1) {
    var button = document.getElementById(sub1);

    if (checkbox.checked === true) {
        button.disabled = "";
    } else {
        button.disabled = "disabled";
    }
}
```

Submit Button:

```
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled"/></p>
```

When I try to reverse select, the submit button doesn't become enable. It works if I go from top to bottom but not the other way around.

[image]
After meeting the if statement condition, the button become enabled. If I were to deselect any of the 2nd of 3rd condition, the submit button is still enabled. It seems the 1st condition have a higher priority.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for conditions in `if` statement is incorrect.

Instead of:

```
if (checkbox.checked === true) && ()
```

Do:

```
if (checkbox.checked === true && somethingElse === false && evenMore === true){
  button.disabled = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add all the checks using `&&` in your first `if` statement:

```
function isChecked(checkbox, sub1) {
    var button = document.getElementById(sub1);
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="CD[]"]');
    var select = document.getElementById('show');

    var atLeastOneCheckbox = false;
    for (var index=0; index<checkboxes.length; ++index) {
        if (checkboxes[index].checked) {
            atLeastOneCheckbox = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (checkbox.checked && atLeastOneCheckbox  && select.value) {
        button.disabled = "";
    } else {
        button.disabled = "disabled";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just asking what does select.valud check for ? for atLeastOneCheckbox, does it check for true condition ?

Comment: oh that was a typo. I meant to say `select.value`. edited

Comment: Thank you. it wasn't working so i play around with the if statement and found that atLeastOneCheckbox is not working.

Comment: second typo, you need to do `document.querySelectorAll` to get a list of all matches, not `document.querySelector`. edited

Comment: Thanks it's working. I updated the question at the bottom for some minor bugs. It seems on the 1st picture if I go reverse direction, selecting from bottom to up the button won't be enabled. On the 2nd picture, if i were to deselect but still leave "I have read and agree...." still selected the submit button would still be enabled.